# Run redshift as soon as internet is connected

Tags: scripting, kde

I have `redshift` installed in my laptop and I've configured to run it on startup. However, it requires an active internet connection to run. But the problem is, my ISP requires me to log in before I get an active connection. So, a connection is not available immediately after booting, and so redshift fails to run.

Is there any way I can run redshift automatically as soon as I get an active connection? I'm on KDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using one of these networks on which you can freely connect, but need to go through a web authentication service before you can send requests anywhere else.

The first solution that comes to mind is to write a wrapper script around `redshift`, and check for an Internet connection regularly, before starting `redshift`. All you'd have to do after that is setup that script to be executed at boot time, instead of `redshift` itself. Here's a first example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! ping -qw1 -c1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    # As long as we can't ping Google's DNS, sleep.
    sleep 5
done

exec /path/to/redshift # We exited the loop, we can run redshift.
```

Now with this solution, there's still a chance of a false positive. If ICMP packets are not blocked, but redirected like the rest of your traffic (to the authentication server), you'll get an ECHO reply, just not from the correct target... An easy way to fix this is to use an HTTP request instead, and check the contents of the page in case we're being fed the authentication page.

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! wget -qO- http://example.com/ | grep -q Example; do
    sleep 5
done

exec /path/to/redshift
```

Whatever solution you pick, don't forget to make your script executable:

```
$ chmod +x redshift_at_boot.sh
```

Then all you have to do is get that script executed instead of `redshift` at boot time. If you don't need `redshift` running as root, you can schedule that script from KDE's *System settings* > *Startup & shutdown* > *Autostart*. If it does require root privileges, then find out how to schedule things at boot time for your distribution. Another possibility using KDE's feature would be to add `gksudo` or `pkexec` after `exec` in the script (assuming you don't mind the password prompt).